# C#: Exchange address to SMTP OR another way of getting SMTP mail from windows contacts?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, exchange-server

I'm trying to find a way (in C#) to read a txt file in which there's a name written, and then the program should search in the address book (of Outlook or even the others address books of Windows) and resolve that name as an SMTP address.

Via OOM i can easily reach Exchange format mail addresses, but i don't know what to do with these, since i build my mail as a MailMessage object, that only supports SMTP addresses.

I've tried different ways:
1-Microsoft.Communications.Contact:

```
`ContactManager cm = new ContactManager();`

`List<Contact> contatti = (List<Contact>)cm.GetContactCollection();`
```

The second row cause me a NullReferenceException.

2-CDO library: i can't obtain anything, because it lacks some important classes such as AddressEntry.

3-MAPI library (CDO 1.2 downloaded from microsoft.com): is only full of interfaces, can't instantiate anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can query AD to get SMTP emails but you need some kind of unique identifier like domain and username otherwise you might get duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben suggests, you might run into problems where the name you have is not unambiguous. You need to be prepared for this.

Apart from that issue you have two options here: Query AD for the information (using System.DirectoryServices or even better System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement). From the entities returned, read the proxyAddresses property. This property contains the addresses of the user or contact.

If you are running Exchange 2007 or later, you can also use the EWS Managed API to resolve the name via Exchange. Use the ResolveNamed method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.exchangeservicebinding.resolvenames(v=exchg.140).aspx

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480

EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx